# Find a basis for set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M_{2n}$ denote the set of all square matrices of size $(2n)\times (2n)$. I managed to show that the following set is a subvector space of $M_{2n}(K)$:

$$
N_{2n}:=\left\{A\in M_{2n}(K): QA+A^\top Q=0\right\}
$$
with $Q\in M_{2n}(K)$ being the block matrix given by
$$
Q:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & E_n\\ -E_n & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $E_n$ is the $n$-dimensional identity matrix.

I am asked to find a basis for $N_{2n}$ and I do not really know how to do that.

---

I started with the special case $n=1$. In this case, if I let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ be in $N_2$, then I get the condition
$$
a = -d
$$
while $c$ and $b$ have no restrictions.

So I think that a basis is given by
$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$

---

In the general case, if I write $A\in N_{2n}$ in block form $A=\begin{pmatrix}B & C\\D & F\end{pmatrix}$, I get the condition
$$
B=-F
$$
but I don't know if this is helpful to find a basis...

Comment: One step towards finding a basis can be to first determine the dimension of the subspace. Do you know the dimension?

Comment: I would think that from $C$ and $D$, since they have no restrictions, I get $2n^2$ matrices in $M_{2n}(K)$ with exactly one entry being $1$ in the upper diagonal matrix and lower diagonal matrix, respecitvely and all others being $0$.  Moreoever, from $B=-F$, I would suspect further $n^2$ matrices... so I would get $3n^2$ but I know it should be $2n^2 + n$...

Comment: You did the computation correctly in the case of $n = 1$, I am not sure about the general case below. Note that $N_{2 n} = \text{ker}(\Phi)$, where $$\Phi \colon M_{2 n}(K) \to M_{2n}(K), \qquad A \mapsto Q A + A^{\mathsf{T}} Q.$$ Now $\Phi(A)^{\mathsf T} = - \Phi(A)$ because $Q^{\mathsf T} = - Q$ and thus the range of $\Phi$ is actually contained in the $2 n \times 2 n$ skew-symmetric matrices. Hence the dimension of the kernel can be at most $(2 n)^2 - \frac{1}{2} (2 n)(2 n - 1) = 2 n^2 + n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations are incorrect, probably because you forgot to transpose the blocks $B,C,D,F$ when computing $A^T$. In fact, $A^T=\pmatrix{B^T & D^T\cr C^T & F^T}$.

Once you write $A^T$ correctly, you find the conditions $D^T=D,C^T=C$ and $F=-B^T$. Hence, $C$ and $D$ are symmetric, so you get $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ free parameters for each, and $B$ is arbitrary, so you get $n^2$ more parameters, so $2\times \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n^2=2n^2+n$ in total, as required.

To find a basis, set one paramater to $1$ and the others to $0$. Doing this for each possibility will give the required basis, as you did for $n=1$ (this procedure can be justified properly...)